# Query performance when searching non-indexed columns

Tags: sql, performance, oracle10g

I have a table where i'm searching for text in two unindexed columns like below

```
select * from Items where items.item_label = 'Mac address' and items.item_value = '023424234324'
```

The `item_label` and `item_value` are both not indexed together. Here item_label is completely optional, i'm adding it so that the DB can find the item by label faster(assuming it would perform better if I narrow down what i'm looking for )

Which query is better, the one above or the one below?

```
select * from Items where items.item_value = '023424234324'
```

Comment: If there are no indexes on any of those columns and the number of rows for those values is the same, then both will most likely perform the same

Comment: Without any relevant indexes to help it, the database needs to scan the whole table looking for matches, whether you have one condition or two in your `WHERE` clause.  If the table is any significant size, then the I/O for that will swamp all other considerations on the query processing side.  If the two queries return the same number of rows then there is no other relevant side to consider.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Lamak and John that both queries will perform the same.  The I/O time to read the data is much larger than the CPU time to perform the comparison.

However, once you start combining those queries with other data, the second, simpler query may perform much better.

---

There is an implicit data correlation between `item_label` and `item_value`.  *You* know the `item_label` predicate returns 10 rows and the `item_value` predicate returns the same 10 rows.  The optimizer does *not* know that.  Instead, it will make a calculation like this: `(low cardinality predicate) AND (low cardinality predicate) = very low cardinality results`.  Those bad estimates can lead to bad execution plans when other tables are added to the query.

Oracle has ways to deal with this issue.  Such as [extended statistics](http://structureddata.org/2007/10/31/oracle-11g-extended-statistics/) in 11g, and automatic SQL directives in 12c.  But it's much better to avoid the issue entirely if possible.  Removing redundant predicates is a good thing.  Don't add a logically unnecessary predicate, unless it specifically adds a performance feature such as partition pruning or index access.